# Deny access to all users except one to access private-folder inside S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a public S3 bucket which has 2 folders inside it, `public-folder` and `private-folder`

I want everyone to access the `public-folder` and I want only `user1` to access `private-folder` programmatically.

Inside the S3 bucket, I have added the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1568654876568",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn-of-user1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/private-folder/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

from the IAM, I have created a policy for `user1` to be able to access the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this goal? Would be possible to deny everyone to access the `private-folder` using S3 policy and then override that using IAM policy that I have defined for `user1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't the following be easier and more natural to do if you have `public-folder` and `private-folder`. The following is based on the fact that buckets and its objects are **private by default**.

#### Bucket policy

It allows public access to `public-folder`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1568654876568",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/public-folder/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### User policy

It allows putting, getting and deleting objects in `private-folder`, as well as listing the bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/private-folder/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Would be possible to deny everyone to access the private-folder using S3 policy and then override that using IAM policy that I have defined for user1?

**Explicit deny** overwrites any allow. Thus if you deny access to everyone, you can't use any IAM policy to allow access.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made the bucket public... The public-folder contain images that everyone should see. With the above solutions, would people be able to see the public images in their browser?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Hi. I don't see a reason why not. Obviously you would have to adjust `Block public access (bucket settings)` settings as well. Nevertheless the easiest way to check, it to verify that. You can setup second bucket to test with some sample files and policy, if you don't want to experiment on the primary bucket.